# How to get started on VOIP programming?

Tags: voip

How to start developping a VoIP product.

I'd like to hear something of the experienced,

thanks in advance!

Comment: what sort of VOIP product? a phone?

Comment: All are fine,they should share something in common,which we can adapt to fit our specific need.

Comment: I think the easiest way if you install a VoIP SDK and use its prewritten VoIP components. I'm experienced in Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK that allows you to develop any VoIP product. Check its online manual that is a good place to start: [http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_100-online-manual-voip.html](http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_100-online-manual-voip.html)

Answer (score 2):

voip programming,voip programming Tutorial, Tutorials voip ...

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorialsearch/?t=voip+programming

What is VoIP and How it Works

http://faq.programmerworld.net/voip/voip.htm

Comment: nice answer = better than my prosposed sarky one.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a site [GNY](http://gonullyourself.org/phreak/)  which seems to include some stuff about voip, in the greater context of phreaking.