# Getting started with Voip programming

Tags: real-time, voip

I need to create a voip application ( like msn ).
What do I need in general ?

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354715/how-to-get-started-on-voip-programming) two weeks ago.

Comment: Please see my answer in another question: [VoIP Programming](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43970929/7877309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by learning about [SIP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol). If you don't want to do everything from scratch, you can take a look at [Sofia-SIP library](http://sofia-sip.sourceforge.net/). Also, looking at some OpenSource Softphone projects (like [Telephone](http://code.google.com/p/telephone/)) might be helpful.

Hope it helps.